# MySQL - nested where condition

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete multiple records from data table. The problem is that if I need to remove 3 records of Deposit I need to look for not only for 'Deposit' keyword but also for 'Balance' keyword.

```
TABLE Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| report_id   action_id   action_name   balance   received   given  item_name   total|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1           1        Balance           0      10        0      Gold         10  |
|    2           2        Deposit          10      10        0      Gold         20  |
|    3           3        Deposit          20      10        0      Gold         30  |
|    4           4        Balance           0       5        0      Silver        5  |
|    5           5        Deposit           5       5        0      Silver       10  |
|    6           6        Deposit          10       5        0      Silver       15  |
|    7           1        Withdraw         30       0       10      Gold         20  |
     ..        .....
```

I have such piece of code:

```
...
// Empty array for keys (action_id, action_name)
$tempArray  = array();  

// Generates string like: '(?,"Deposit"),(?,"Deposit")'
$var = implode(',', array_fill(0,count($tempArray), '(?,"Deposit")')); 

// Generates query like: DELETE FROM Report WHERE (action_id, action_name) IN ((?,"Deposit"),(?,"Deposit")) 
$sql = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE (action_id, action_name) IN (".$var.")";

try{

$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute(array_values($tempArray));
...
```

What I am trying to do:

```
...
// Generate string like: '(?,"Deposit" OR "Balance"),(?,"Deposit" OR "Balance")'
$var = implode(',', array_fill(0,count($tempArray), '(?,"Deposit" OR "Balance")')); 

// Generate query like: DELETE FROM Report WHERE (action_id, action_name) IN ((?,"Deposit" OR "Balance"),(?,"Deposit" OR "Balance")) 
$sql = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE (action_id, action_name) IN (".$var.")";
```

I thought maybe this could work:

```
...
// Generate string like: '(?,"Deposit","Balance"),(?,"Deposit","Balance")'
$var = implode(',', array_fill(0,count($tempArray), '(?,"Deposit","Balance")')); 

// Generate query like: DELETE FROM Report WHERE (action_id, action_name,action_name) IN ((?,"Deposit","Balance"),(?,"Deposit","Balance")) 
$sql = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE (action_id, action_name,action_name) IN (".$var.")";
```

Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Updating my answer because now it's clear that `action_id` is not unique.

Can you modify your query like this:

```
$var = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($tempArray), '?'));
$sql = "DELETE FROM Report WHERE action_id IN ($var) ".
       "AND action_name IN ('Deposit', 'Balance')";

$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute(array_values($tempArray));
```

Comment: Sorry for obscurity. I updated my question. 'action_id' is non-unique identifier.